# Single word for people who are like "a frog in the well"

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, adjectives

Is there a single word describing someone who is like *a frog in a well*? The frog believes the well is the entire world. How can I describe people who think that their own small environment is the entire world?

Comment: Are you looking for something negative, or more neutral?

Comment: There is also a Sanskrit word which could be transliterated as koop-mundook (literally, frog in a well) for which Ankit could be seeking an English equivalent.  Since Sanskrit and Latin are in the Indo-European group of languages, is there something similar in Latin that could have descended into English?

Comment: @DilipSarwate Or, since English is a Germanic language, is there something similar in Proto-Germanic that could have descended into English?

Comment: I have no suggestion on my own but I do not like most of the existing suggestions. The frog in the well is not aware that there is a world outside the well. "Parochial," for example, is about knowing that there is a world outside but not being interested. "Blinkered" is perhaps the best except that being blinkered is the result of someone else's actions.

Comment: This reminds me of [Plato's Allegory of the Cave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_of_the_Cave).

Comment: @Dilip _Koop-mundook_ is not Sanskrit, at least not according to standard transliteration—it's Hindi if anything. The normal transliteration is _kūpa-maṇḍūka_.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Synonyms of *[parochial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parochial)*, "characterized by an unsophisticated focus on local concerns to the exclusion of wider contexts", may serve.  Such [synonyms](http://dico.isc.cnrs.fr/dico/en/search?b=1&r=parochial&send=Look+it+up) include *confined, insular, limited, local, narrow, narrow-minded, petty, provincial, regional, small-minded, isolated*.

*[Insular](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/insular)*, for example, has a sense that means "separate or isolated from the surroundings; having little interaction with external parties; [provincial](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/provincial#Adjective)."  *Narrow-minded* and *small-minded* are of course easily understood, and so would be *close-minded*.

*Blinkered*, fitted with *[blinkers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blinker#Noun)*, or "eye shields attached to a hood for horses, to prevent them from seeing backwards and partially sideways", is another possibility, as are formations from synonyms *[blinders](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blinders)* and *[winkers](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/winkers)*.

*Edit:* Also consider *[monomania](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/monomania)*, "excessive interest or concentration on a singular object or subject" or "a pathological obsession with one person, thing or idea"; *[obsession](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/obsession)*, "compulsive or irrational preoccupation; an unhealthy fixation"; *[idée fixe](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/id%C3%A9e_fixe#Noun)*;
*[tunnel vision](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tunnel+vision)*, "an extremely narrow point of view; narrow-mindedness"; and *[locked-in](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/locked-in_syndrome)*.

Comment: 'provincial' and 'narrow-minded' are my choices from your list.

Comment: This an excellent answer!

Answer (score 19):

I would add *myopic* to @jwpat7's excellent list.

Comment: +1 for myopic, the nearsightedness is much more descriptive of the predicament.

Answer (score 6):

One term you could use is *isolationist*, although [isolationism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolationism) is used mostly to describe countries who do not interact internationally and focus on themselves. It might be understood when used to describe people, however.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on how far you want to take your analogy, you could label the frog a *[solipsist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solipsist)*.

Comment: I was thinking the same thing, though arguably, if there were more than 1 frog in that well, he'd have a harder time maintaining the viewpoint that he were the centre of his universe...

Answer (score 4):

I believe "provincial" is the best match for what you are asking for, but only if you want a pejorative term.  Although, I find it hard to imagine making this observation about someone and it not being intended pejoratively.

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking more *[navel-gazing](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/navel-gazing)*...except that frogs don't have navels to my knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

I would go for "self-centered and lacking in situational context".

A more colloquial term would be that the person is "wearing blinders", which comes from horses wearing [blinders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinders) to prevent them from seeing things that could potentially startle or alarm them.

Another term would be that the person "has buried their head in the sand" which refers to the (false) legend that ostriches bury their heads in the sand to avoid danger.

Answer (score 1):

Five years and no one has suggested *[cloistered](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cloistered)*.

> 1. dwelling or raised in, or as if in, cloisters; solitary.
> 2. isolated, protected, hidden away for the sake of maintaining innocence
> 3. naive, lacking in worldliness

A *cloister* is a place of religious seclusion, like some convents and monasteries.

Answer (score 1):

Two words, not one: [**ivory tower**](https://www.google.it/search?q=risposte&oq=risposte&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22ivory%20tower%20definition%22)

> 1. a state of privileged seclusion or separation from the facts and practicalities of the real world
> 2. To ​live or be in an ​ivory ​tower **is not to ​know about** or to ​want to ​avoid **the ​ordinary and ​unpleasant things that ​happen in people's ​lives**:
> 3. a place or situation where you are separated from the difficulties of ordinary life and so are unable to understand them, used especially to describe a college or university:
> 4. an attitude of aloofness from or **disdain or disregard for worldly or practical affairs.**

<sub>Citations taken from "ivory tower definition"</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

I would call him **Introvert** and **blinder** as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider *small-town* and *shortsighted*.

> [**small-town**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/small-town): limited in outlook or experience; unsophisticated; provincial.
>
> [**shortsighted**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/shortsighted): lacking foresight or scope.