# What's the word for "believing one is the center of the universe"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I want to describe a character who thinks that the world revolves around him, thus he believes he is the center of the universe.

Is there a single word having the meaning of *center of (one's) universe*?

Comment: Sounds like he might be _self-centered_ or _egocentric_.

Comment: Why do you want a single word?  The expression that someone *thinks he's the center of the universe* is exactly for your purpose.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou I'm seeking a better phrase/term, any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for a word for what this guy is?  Or a term for *the center of the universe* as part of your question says?  Please clarify.

Comment: @GeorgePompidou I want a term for _the center of the universe_  to describe his case. Other suggestion are welcome.

Comment: Then there is no *better* term for that.  That is literally, exactly, specifically what you are looking for.

Comment: One who thinks the world revolves around him is *geophysically ignorant* (unless actually at the center of a world, in which case *well-informed* is appropriate).

Comment: Everyone is right that there isn't a better word for what you're trying to say; if you want an alternative phrase, you could say "He's the most important person in his life."  In this context, "he" and "his" both refer to the same character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The word *[egoist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egoist#Noun)* is slightly different from *[egotist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egotist#Noun)*; its senses include  “An egocentric or self-centered person”. *[Narcissist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/narcissist#Noun)*, with sense  “One who shows extreme love and admiration for himself or herself”, and *[solipsist](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solipsist#Noun)*, “One who adheres to self-absorption and an ignorance of the views or needs of others”,  may be relevant too.

*Edit:* As mentioned in comments and as used in the definition of *egoist* above, *[egocentric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/egocentric#Adjective)* has senses like  “selfish, self-centered” and  “egotistical”.  It also has a less-obvious sense:

> Relating to spatial representations: linked to a reference frame based on one’s own location within the environment (as when giving the direction as “right” rather than “north”); opposed to [allocentric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/allocentric#Adjective).

[Link sources: wiktionary and ELU [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124190/what-do-you-call-someone-who-lives-for-himself),[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/176875/a-person-who-cannot-understand-that-there-may-be-other-perspectives),[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/65472/word-for-only-caring-about-oneself),[4](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107378/word-to-describe-someone-who-does-whatever-they-please)].

Comment: Hmm. Scope for a few duplicate questions here, I think, then.

Comment: Any particular reason you didn't include egocentric, which literally means "self-in-the-center", aka "self-centered?"

Comment: @DanBron, it was mentioned in Matt Gutting's comment so I didn't remention it; but now have added a note about it.  Thanks!

Comment: +1, for though it's not a single word for "the absolute center of the universe", it *does* answer the question "what do you call someone *who believes himself to be* the absolute center of the universe?"

Comment: The funny thing is that he’s probably right. See these related questions: [0](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/669), [1](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88217), [2](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88217), [3](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/25591), [4](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/91162).

Answer (score 0):

I think [egomaniacal](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Egomaniacal) conveys the idea of being the centre of the universe :

> - (Psychology) obsessive love for oneself and regard for one's own needs
> - (Psychology) any action dictated by this point of view

Source:http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Egomaniacal